# Oracle SQL get last Sunday

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently using the below statement to sucessfully get it

```
SELECT
    next_day(sysdate-7, 'Sunday')
FROM
    dual;
```

Is there any more elegant way to get it? If I try to use last_day, it gives an error.

Comment: looks ok to me.

Comment: This looks pretty elegant to me.  Just try doing this in SQL Server!

Comment: `last_day` returns last day of the month. What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: `trunc(sysdste, 'IW') - 1` : without NLS parameters

Comment: Your existing query will produce an output on "last Sunday" but with time-of-day equal to that of `SYSDATE`. Is that what you need? Or do you also need it truncated to midnight? If you need it truncated to midnight, then you can use the expression in @astentx's comment, right above this one.

Comment: @astentx thanks! Could you explain how it works?

Comment: @JaviTorre It's better to check [Datetime Format Model](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) and [`trunc`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm#SQLRF06151) function description in the documentation. It truncates (`trunc`) the date to the beginning of the ISO week (`IW`) (which starts from the Monday) and takes the previous (`-1`) day (Sunday).

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to post it as an answer so I can choose it as best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel not comfortable with NLS session parameters, which is required for `next_day` function, you can use [`trunc`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm#i79761) function: truncate your date to ISO week, that starts from Monday, and subtract one day to get to Sunday.

But keep in mind, that Oracle's date is essentially a date and time, and `trunc` function sets all the lower granularity elements  of date (lower than truncation unit) to their initial values, so you'll get to the midnight of the previous Sunday. In contrast, `next_day` preserves the time portion, so two dates retrieved with `next_day` and `trunc` will not be equal in full.

If you need to keep the same result, but without NLS dependency, you can do some interval calculations, that will preserve the time portion.

More about date and time format elements can be found [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

Below is all the above solutions compared:

> ```
> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
> ```

> ```
> select
>   --IW here stands for ISO week
>   trunc(sysdate, 'IW') - 1 as dt_trunc,
>   next_day(sysdate - 7, 'Sunday') as dt_next_day,
>   --double quoted part in date format is needed to embed string constants in the format
>   sysdate - to_dsinterval(to_char(sysdate, 'D "00:00:00"')) + 1 as dt_interval
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> DT_TRUNC            | DT_NEXT_DAY         | DT_INTERVAL        
> :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------
> 2021-04-18 00:00:00 | 2021-04-18 18:02:42 | 2021-04-18 18:02:42
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=164918ef6522f6f0f0be7310317fbfb8)*